# Parse Recursive Collect Deep Nested Category XML childrens with Parents Ids

Tags: ruby, xml, xml-parsing, nokogiri

I have a XML file like with id and name attributes.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <product_categories>
       <product_category id="409" name="Computer">
          <product_category id="414" name="Server">
             <product_category id="511" name="Multimedia Server"/>
          </product_category>
          <product_category id="1645" name="Server Equips"/>
       </product_category>
       <product_category id="97" name="Computer Equips">
          <product_category id="127" name="Adaptor">
             <product_category id="133" name="Audior"/>
             <product_category id="128" name="DVI"/>
             <product_category id="134" name="Firewire"/>
             <product_category id="135" name="Gender Changer"/>
             <product_category id="129" name="HDMI - DVI / DVI-I"/>
             <product_category id="137" name="HDMI"/>
             <product_category id="139" name="Keyboard"/>
             <product_category id="141" name="Mouse"/>
             <product_category id="144" name="Scart"/>
             <product_category id="196" name="Serial"/>
             <product_category id="198" name="SUN KVM"/>
             <product_category id="147" name="USB Adap">
                <product_category id="743" name="USB Adap"/>
                <product_category id="1040" name="USB Şarj Adap"/>
                <product_category id="1088" name="USB C Adap"/>
                <product_category id="1611" name="USB Seri Adap"/>
                <product_category id="1612" name="USB Ethernet Adap"/>
             </product_category>
            </product_category>
          </product_category>
       </product_category>
    </product_categories>
```

I want to make a list all children with parents ids and parents with self id. Example:

```
    Computer, [409]
      Server, [409,414]
        Multimedia Server, [409,414,511]
    Computer Equips, [97]
      Adaptor, [97,127]
        Audior, [97,127,133]
        ...
        ...
          USB Adap, [97,127,147,743]
```

I try to solve my problem for weeks but could not find the solution? 
How can i recursive parse and convert like that using ruby and nokogiri? Any suggestion.

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". You did not show code or tell us what is wrong with it. As is, you're asking us to write code for you which is off topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick. It simply iterates through all 'product_category' nodes. For each node it gets the ancestor IDs and then prints the names and IDs.

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open('test.xml'))
doc.search('product_category').each do |node|
  # get the current node's ID
  id = node.attr('id')

  # get all ancestor node IDs
  ancestor_ids = node.ancestors('product_category').map { |anode| anode.attr('id') }

  # put all the node IDs into an array
  all_ids = ([id] + ancestor_ids).reverse

  # output node name with all IDs and prepend spaces based on number of ancestors
  puts "#{'  ' * ancestor_ids.size}#{node.attr('name')}, [#{all_ids.join(', ')}]"
end
```

The output is:

```
Computer, [409]
  Server, [409, 414]
    Multimedia Server, [409, 414, 511]
  Server Equips, [409, 1645]
Computer Equips, [97]
  Adaptor, [97, 127]
    Audior, [97, 127, 133]
    DVI, [97, 127, 128]
    Firewire, [97, 127, 134]
    Gender Changer, [97, 127, 135]
    HDMI - DVI / DVI-I, [97, 127, 129]
    HDMI, [97, 127, 137]
    Keyboard, [97, 127, 139]
    Mouse, [97, 127, 141]
    Scart, [97, 127, 144]
    Serial, [97, 127, 196]
    SUN KVM, [97, 127, 198]
    USB Adap, [97, 127, 147]
      USB Adap, [97, 127, 147, 743]
      USB Şarj Adap, [97, 127, 147, 1040]
      USB C Adap, [97, 127, 147, 1088]
      USB Seri Adap, [97, 127, 147, 1611]
      USB Ethernet Adap, [97, 127, 147, 1612]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This solution gives me what I want. I'm very happy to learn about the situation between the **search** method and the **ancestors** method. My best regards.